# Can not bind socket in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets

There is my function. I pass argument port as 80 and I always can not bind socket.

```
int create_socket(int port)
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in name;

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not create socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //Assigning a name to the socket
    name.sin_family = AF_INET;
    name.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
    name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(sock, (const struct sockaddr *) &name, sizeof(name)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can not bind socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return sock;
}
```

Comment: If only there was a function to print what is the error like `perror()`

Comment: The output is "Can not bind socket: Permission denied"

Comment: Ok, then I have to take back my guess: You need a higher privilege level (i.e. Administrator/root) to bind ports <= 1024

Comment: So i need to run program with sudo?

Comment: That would be an option, yes

Comment: @МаксимБелан you need to replace name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); to name.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

Refer [1] for more info.     
  
[1] http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html

Comment: @PrabhakarLad: Though what you say is techically true, note that `INADDR_ANY` is 0, so `htonl(INADDR_ANY) == INADDR_ANY`

Answer (score 5):

Typically port number less than 1024 are used by well known network servers and in linux, root privilege is required to open these ports.

80 is HTTP port and so your program requires root privilege.